# Focal Length in Walk/Fly Navigation Mode

Tags: camera, navigation

How do I change the focal length in Walk/Fly Navigation Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use **Fly/Walk Navigation in 3D View** and adjust the focal length, open up the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> go to *View* and set the *Focal Length* property for the actual *viewport*:

[image]

If **in Camera**, select the *Camera* go to *Properties > Object Data (camera icon)* and set the *Focal Length* property to what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the docs of [Fly/Walk doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/walk_fly.html#dview-fly-walk) - I think the focal length change is not available.

I think if you can bind a keyboard shortcut with some python scripting, maybe you could achieve that.